# Concatenate only when data is not null in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have a table with some data in my oracle table

| S.ID | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 21 |
| 2 | Mike | 23 |
| 3 | Daniel | null |
| 4 | Josh |  |

Now I want to concatenate these 3 columns as a single column and my result should be as below

| Details |
| --- |
| Adam (1-21) |
| Mike (2-23) |
| Daniel (3) |
| Josh (4) |

When there is both S.ID and age, both should be enclosed within the braces separated by a hyphen. Eg: Adam (1-21)

When the age value is null or if it doesn't have any value, only S.ID should be enclosed within the brace. There shouldn't be hyphen beside the S.ID and "null" inside the braces. Eg: Daniel (3)

I'm finding difficultly doing the same using a query in oracle.

Comment: "When the age value is null or if it doesn't have any value" - in Oracle, that's just the same. NULL is *absence* of a value. What does "null" in Daniel's row represent? A string (literally 'null'), or ...?

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following

```sql
SELECT
     "Name" || ' (' || "S.ID" || CASE 
         WHEN "Age" IS NULL OR TRIM("Age")='' THEN ''
         ELSE '-' || "Age"
     END || ')' as Details
FROM tb
```

It uses a case expression to check for nulls and empty values for age before including it in the string.

[View working demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a49e5917337a609bab13ca3bc077fb9)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/NVL2.html#GUID-414D6E81-9627-4163-8AC2-BD24E57742AE) function is handy for cases of **non-null** values, use it in such a way that

```sql
SELECT '('||id||NVL2(age,'-'||age,'')||')' AS "Details"
  FROM t
```

| Details |
| --- |
| (1-21) |
| (2-23) |
| (3) |
| (4) |

the hyphens are prepended only for non-null age values of which both labeled *null* and *non-labeled* values are considered as *null* values, even as of nature for an integer type as been presumed data types for age column.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=174aeec1f37f15351748b05128da634a)</kbd>